# How to use Firefox profiles in Selenium Python (windows)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm unable lo load my Firefox profile on the Selenium Webdriver.

i have tried several ways commented here on SO, but non did the trick. Either i loose connection to the driver or the profile does not get loaded.

this is what i have so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = Options()
options.headless = False
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(r'C:\\Users\\xxXX\\AppData\\Local\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\y73h6ogb.default-release')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(fp, options=options, executable_path='geckodriver/geckodriver.exe')

driver.get(URL)
```

Comment: yes but i was not able to make it work. keep getting the temp profile

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver) you can load a profile like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox, FirefoxOptions, FirefoxProfile


options = FirefoxOptions()
options.headless = True

profile = FirefoxProfile("PATH_TO_PROFILE\\1234asdf.some_profile")

driver = Firefox(
    firefox_profile=profile,
    executable_path="PATH_TO_DRIVER\\geckodriver.exe",
    options=options,
)

driver.get("https://python.org")
driver.close()
```

Or by adding the profile to the [options](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.firefox.options.Options.profile):

```
...
options = FirefoxOptions()
options.headless = True
options.profile = FirefoxProfile("PATH_TO_PROFILE\\1234asdf.some_profile")

driver = Firefox(
    executable_path="PATH_TO_DRIVER\\geckodriver.exe",
    options=options,
)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

By using webdriver for firefox, You will be able to do that!